# Gradle TestNG fails but running TestNG independently works fine in Eclipse

Tags: java, gradle, testng

I have a gradle test task like below:

```
test {
     useTestNG() {
     }
}
```

But it gives me an error when I run gradle build

> Gradle suite > Gradle test > com.myproject.test.FirstTest > startCassandra FAILED
>       java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: DIGIT
>           at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.format.SSTableFormat$Type.(SSTableFormat.java:58)
>           at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.format.SSTableFormat$Type.(SSTableFormat.java:46)
>           at org.apache.cassandra.config.DatabaseDescriptor.(DatabaseDescriptor.java:87)

But if I run the test class as TestNG test by right clicking it -> Run As -> TestNG, it runs fine.

What could be causing the discrepancy? I've been trying to figure out what I did wrong but it seems like it's only failing when I'm trying to run the test through Gradle.

Comment: You have most probably differences in the versions of the jar dependency at runtime.

Comment: I'm using org.cassandraunit:cassandra-unit:3.1.3.2 and com.datastax.cassandra:cassandra-driver-core 3.3.0 .  How do I check if I'm using different jars at runtime?

Answer (score 0):

I think your error related to the below JIRA from Apache

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-15245

Answer (score 0):

Datastax provides shaded Guava lib as below, I removed actual Guava lib and added the below it works fine to me.

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>com.datastax.oss</groupId>
            <artifactId>java-driver-shaded-guava</artifactId>
            <version>25.1-jre</version>
        </dependency>
```